# Q about Problem 19-2 in "Lisp" by Winston and Horn

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Problem 19-2 in "Lisp" by Winston and Horn states,

> In depth-first  search, all of the
>   partial paths in the queue at a given
>   point in the  search are related to
>   one another in a simple way: each is
>   the  extension by one node of the
>   partial path after it in the queue. 
>   The  queue might, for example, look
>   like this: 
>        `((D C B A) (C B A) (B A) (A))`

However, I don't see how that's the case.  For example, I get output 
like the following:

```
(depth-first 's 'f) 
queue: ((S)) 
(S) 
queue: ((A S) (D S)) 
(S A) 
queue: ((B A S) (D A S) (D S)) 
(S A B) 
queue: ((C B A S) (E B A S) (D A S) (D S)) 
(S A B C) 
queue: ((E B A S) (D A S) (D S)) 
(S A B E) 
queue: ((D E B A S) (F E B A S) (D A S) (D S)) 
(S A B E D) 
queue: ((F E B A S) (D A S) (D S)) 
(S A B E F)
```

where I put a print statement at the beginning of the routine:

```
(defun depth-first (start finish &optional 
                    (queue (list (list start)))) 
  (format t "~%queue: ~a" queue) 
  (cond ((endp queue) nil) 
        ((eq finish (first (first queue))) 
         (reverse (first queue))) 
        (t (depth-first 
            start 
            finish 
            (append (extend (first queue)) 
                    (rest queue))))))
```

In this case, no partial path in the queue is the extension by one 
node of the partial path after it in the queue. 
Is this a misprint in the exercise or is there some input that does 
actually give the queue he gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [answer](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.lisp/browse_thread/thread/1431086bbc4d701c#) by Pascal Bourguignon.